# guardar la foto tomada

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema, mi aplicación abre la camara, toma la imagen y la muestra dentro de la aplicación recién tomada. pero al entrar a galeria no está, necesito poder guardarla en la galeria. También encontré que ACTION MEDIA SCANNER ya no sirve en nuevas versiones. Tengo el emulador con el API 28

```js
private void galleryAddPic() {

       Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(Path);
        Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        galleryIntent.setData(picUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(galleryIntent);

    }
```

Si hago un toast, sale esto: file://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/Pictures/imagen12.jpg
Y es en esa ruta donde me la guarda, yo la necesito en: 
//storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera

Answer (score 0):

**ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE**
Acción de intención estándar que se puede enviar para que la aplicación de la cámara capture una imagen y la devuelva.

**EXTRA_OUTPUT** utilizado para indicar un Uri de resolución de contenido que se utilizará para almacenar la imagen o el video solicitado.

```
    private void saveImage() {
          Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          File file = new File(Path);
          Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
          galleryIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
    }
```

Comment: Se necesita poder guardarla en la galería., ¿Como se puede guardar en la galería?, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Gracias,ya intente con tu codigo pero la foto me la guardar en esta ruta /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/Pictures/imagen12.jpg, y en la aplicación de galería me sigue sin salir ya que la ruta de camara es (/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/img.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Lo importante es definir el path donde se guardará la imagen, para obtener el directorio

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/
```

realizalo de esta forma:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+"/Camera/";
  File file = new File(Path);
```

Comment: Estoy ocupando tu código y me sale aun en esta ruta (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/Pictures/imagen1.jpg)

Comment: Que raro si usas : Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() precisamente apunta al directorio DCIM : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera

Comment: espera, es que las lineas que me dices en que metodo tendria que iir? ya que yo lo puse en este y a lo mejor por eso no me sirve

Comment: private void galleryAddPic() {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()+"/Camera/";
        File file = new File(path);
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //File file = new File(mAbsolutePath);
        Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        galleryIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + picUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

Comment: O VA EN ESTE OTRO METODO, YA QUE CUANDO LO PUSE EN ESTE ME MARCA UN ERROR private File createPhotoFile() throws IOException {
   String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date());
   String imageFileName = "imagen" + timestamp;

   File storageFile = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
   File photoFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageFile);
   mAbsolutePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
   return photoFile;
}

Comment: por favor ayudame, necesito esto para un proyecto y no me queda

Comment: @Ricardo imprime que es lo que obtienes  mediante : Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath()

Comment: cuando lo imprimó si sale la ruta que deseo ( /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera) pero me lo sigue guardando solo en (/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/Pictures/)

Comment: esto quiere decir que la ruta si sale bien pero al guardarla no