# abrir la galeria, seleccionar una imagen y enviar la por correo

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una app en Android Studio, al momento de presionar un botón quiero que me abra la galería de fotos, pueda seleccionar una foto, regresarse a la app, para enviar el correo con foto.
De momento ya tengo este codigo sirve para enviar el correo sin la foto, la imagen ya me abre la galeria pero no puedo seleccionar la imagen

```js
 Intent intentimagen = new Intent();
        intentimagen.setType("image/");
        intentimagen.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentimagen,"Selecciona una imagen"),GALLERY_REQUEST);

String dest = destinatario.getText().toString().trim();
        String titulo = asunto.getText().toString().trim();
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:" + dest));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titulo);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Chooser Title"));
```

Comment: seria la misma pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/339773/guardar-la-foto-tomada

Comment: No , son diferentes actividades, esta solo tengo que escoger cualquier foto o imagen

Comment: En la otra que pregunte anteriormente tengo que tomar una foto y guardarla en la galeria, pero no es la misma pregunta, y están en actividades diferentes

Comment: Abre el navegador, ve a google y escribe: _abrir galería y seleccionar foto android studio_. Tienes montones de tutoriales. Empieza con uno y cuando tengas alguna duda concreta, vuelves, publicas el código que tengas hecho y preguntas lo que quieras.

Comment: Si ya busque tutoriales, por algo estoy preguntando aquí ya que en los tutoriales el código me sale con errores. Si lees bien me pregunta, ya puse en pedazo de código, que es lo único que funciona